# React - Conditionally rendering component inside component

Tags: reactjs, components

In a React project, I have `Itinerary.tsx`, `ItineraryDetails.tsx`, `Description.tsx`, `Weather.tsx` and `WeatherDetails.tsx` components.

Inside `Itinerary.tsx` I have something like this:

```
<ItineraryDetails>
 <Description/>
</ItineraryDetails>
```

Inside `Weather.tsx` I have something like this:

```
<WeatherDetails>
 <Description/>
</WeatherDetails>
```

Inside `Description.tsx` I have several other elements and a link before a badge:

```
      <Link>
      </Link>
      <Badge>
      </Badge>
```

Since everything besides the link is the same for both `Itinerary.tsx` and `Weather.tsx`, can I use `Description.tsx` for both and somehow conditionally render the link only when inside `Itinerary.tsx`? Or is it better to create 2 "Descriptions"? I'm thinking that having 2 components so similar is a waste and it's not practical once you need to do changes.

I can't just add the link after `ItineraryDetails` or before `Description` because of the html elements' order (the link should appear before the badge).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass a property to the `Description` component:

```js
{this.props.showLink && <Link></Link>}
<Badge></Badge>
```

And then use it like so:

```js
<ItineraryDetails>
 <Description showLink />
</ItineraryDetails>
<WeatherDetails>
 <Description/>
</WeatherDetails>
```